# Reset <input> text after @onchange

Tags: blazor

I'm building a blazor component that will revert back to the original input if the entered text is not valid.
Since `ValueText` doesn't change the rendering process won't update it/replace user input.

```
<input type="text"
       value="@ValueText"
       @onchange="TextChanged" />
```

Calling `StateHasChanged()` won't change the result.

In my case `ValueText` is always empty.
The workaround has been to alternate between `null` and `""` that will cause the input to be reset.

Is there a method to mark the element attribute as "dirty" so the blazor rendering will refresh the DOM even though the virtual DOM is not changed?

Comment: Appears there's an [issue being related to this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17281).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternate the value set to `ValueText`.
This will cause a change in the virtual DOM and cause the DOM to be updated.
By using a special non-printable unicode character it won't affect the visual or interactive behavior.
Since the event can be triggered several times before the diff algorithm is executed we can't rely on a single swap between two values, here I have choosen the arbitrary 10 number of alternative values.

Eventually with [#17281](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17281) it wont be needed anymore.

Make sure to remove `workaroundChar` when parsing the input.

Instead of

```
ValueText = "";
```

use

```
    int workaroundIndex = 0;
    const string workaroundChar = "\u00AD";

    void SetValueText(string? text)
    {
            //Special case for empty values, otherwise the unicode character will hide the placeholder.
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
            {
                if (text == null)
                    ValueText = "";
                else
                    ValueText = null;
                return;
            }

            string w = "";
            for (int n = 0; n < workaroundIndex; n++)
                w += workaroundChar;

            ValueText = text + w;

            workaroundIndex = (workaroundIndex + 1) % 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ValueText  = "";
await Task.Delay(1); //Magic!  
StateHasChanged();
ValueText  = value;
StateHasChanged();
```

thanks for 
 https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17281#issuecomment-620541274

Comment: Yes that's my comment in that issue :)  
  
The keyword is "Magic", the solution needs an explanation why it's working. Weird cases like these might be working today, but not tomorrow, it might work in one browser but not the other.  
  
I'm not saying it's not a good solution in the end, but we need to know why.

Answer (score 1):

When you set an attribute value in Blazor (or Razor) and the value is `null` then the attribute is removed. Hence `value=@ValueText` would not update the value.

Setting the value to an empty string fixes this:

```
<input type="text" value=@ValueText @onchange="TextChanged" />
@if (isValid)
{
    <span class="text-success">✔</span>
}
<p>
    Current value is: @ValueText
</p>

@code
{
    string ValueText = null;
    bool isValid = false;

    void TextChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        // only accept values starting with 'a'
        string newValue = (string)e.Value;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newValue) && newValue.StartsWith('a'))
        {
            // accept
            ValueText = newValue;
            isValid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ValueText = "";
            isValid = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This example will only permit a value that starts with 'a':

[image: demo showing accepted value]

Comment: Sorry your example have the same problem as my attempts. Upon first wrong entry, the input text is set to empty, however on the second attempt, entering an invalid input the entered text remains. My explanation is that your code, as well as mine, doesn't modify the virtual dom, it's still "" so the content won't be sent to the DOM.

Comment: Hmm so it does. Not sure what to recommend - I did see a code sample in the docs which might point in the right direction: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#code-try-15

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an **input value property**, customize its **setter**, and add a field to store the value

In Your **HTML** **section**

```
<input @bind=@inputBindValue />
```

Then in the **@code** **section**

```
  private string _privateValue = string.Empty;

private string inputBindValue
{
    get => _privateValue;

    set
    {
        if( InputIsValid(value) ) return; // check if valid - if yes, then do nothing

        // do stuff if input value is not valid

        _privateValue = string.Empty; // empty Your input field value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @W.S. KK answer in NET 6 you can simplify with this

```
ValueText  = "";
await Task.Yield(); //Magic!  
ValueText  = value;
```

Answer (score -1):

KISS - Keep It Simple...

HTML:

```
<input type="file" value="@_fileValue"@onchange="async () => await OpenFileAsync()" />
```

Code:

```
fileValue = _fileValue == null ? "" : null;
```